# Периодическое выполнение метода с возможностью отмены

Tags: c#, методы

```
class Repeater<T>  where T 
    : struct
{
    Func<T> func;
    T trueResult;

    T currentResult;

    readonly int MaxAttemps;
    private int _attempt;

    CancellationToken token;
    Timer timer = null;

    public Repeater(Func<T> func, T trueResult, int maxAttemps, CancellationToken token)
    {            
        _attempt = 0;
        this.token = token;
        MaxAttemps = maxAttemps;
        this.func = func;
        this.trueResult = trueResult;    
    }

    public void start()
    {            
       bool needStop = false;

        TimeSpan DISABLED_TIME_SPAN = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);
        TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

        using (timer =
          new Timer(delegate(object s)
              {                                           
                  _attempt++;
                  currentResult = func();

                  Console.WriteLine(_attempt);
                  Console.WriteLine(currentResult);
                  Console.WriteLine(currentResult.Equals(trueResult));

                  if (_attempt == MaxAttemps || token.IsCancellationRequested || currentResult.Equals(trueResult))
                  {
                      needStop = true;                          
                  }

                  try
                  {
                      timer.Change(interval, DISABLED_TIME_SPAN);
                  }
                  catch (ObjectDisposedException timerHasBeenDisposed)
                  {

                  }

              }, null, interval, DISABLED_TIME_SPAN))
        {

            do
            {
                this.stop();

            } while (!needStop || token.IsCancellationRequested);
        }

    }

    public void stop()
    { 
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

.Net FrameWork 4.0 client profile.

Данный класс выполняет некое действие `Func<T>` func до выполнения одного из условий

1. Получен необходимый результат функции `Func<T> func = T trueResult;`
2. Достигнуто макс. количество попыток выполнения функции `MaxAttemps`
3. Или получен запрос на прерывание через `CancellationToken token`

Проблема в следующем:
Использоваться данный класс планируется так

```
CancelationSource cs = new CancelationSource;

CancellationToken token = cs.Token;

//Попытка соединения с сервером
var session = new ServerSession("http...");

var repeater = new Repeater(session.Connect(), ConnectionStatus.Connected, 5, token);

repeater.Start();

//Этот кусок кода выполняется только в случае успешного завершения соединения 
if (session.Status == ConnectionStatus.Connected)
    ProcessData(session.GetDataFromServer());
else
    return false;

return true;
```

Что бы все это зарботало как надо пришлось в Repeater.Start() вставить цикл do...while и проверять значение флага bool needStop, иначе получить признак призн отмены операции через token невозможно в момент когда таймер находится в режим отсчета периода до следующего выполнения функции. Но использовать цикл как мне кажется слишком затратно для процессорного времени, есть ли другой способ? Или может быть оставить так?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890915/is-there-a-task-based-replacement-for-system-threading-timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеет ли смысл Start обернуть в поток и при надобности его завершать.